# Creating a word document (docx) with OpenXml

Tags: c#, .net-core, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

Let me start by saying that I have read other similar questions, but the solution (copied below) just doesn't work for me.

I am trying to create a word document (docx) with .net core and OpenXMl (using DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.7.2 nuget package) .
Looks trivial, but somehow it doesn't work. When I try to open the document, I get the error that file is corrupted, truncated or in incorrect format.

Here is my code (I found it in the numerous tutorials):

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System.IO;

public Stream GetDocument()
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();

            using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();

                new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);

                Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;
                body.Append(new Paragraph(
                            new Run(
                                new Text("Hello World!"))));

                mainPart.Document.Save();

            }
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return stream;

        }
```

Ad save it like this:

```
 public static void Test()
        {
            DocxWriter writer = new DocxWriter();

            string filepath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"/test.docx";

            var stream = writer.GetDocument();

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }

            stream.Dispose();
        }
```

EDIT: 
After I extract the docx I can find an underlying xml looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Hello World!</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Comment: Which version of office are you using to open the .docx file?

Comment: @Niladri Actually, I am opening it from the Mac, without office, but I have no problems opening other docx files. I've asked others to try to open it on windows, and it shows similar problem. That is why I don't think it's problem in reader.

Comment: I just verified that this works fine.  Built, ran and generated file on Win10.  and file opens in Word2016.  Can you post more details about your project because so far all of this is working fine.

Comment: I also emailed the file to my mac and it opened on Word for mac.

Answer (score 3):

So my solution looks like this. I have few global variables:

```
private MemoryStream _Ms;
private WordprocessingDocument _Wpd;
```

Then the creation method looks like this:

```
public Doc()
{
    _Ms = new MemoryStream();
    _Wpd = WordprocessingDocument.Create(_Ms, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true);
    _Wpd.AddMainDocumentPart();
    _Wpd.MainDocumentPart.Document = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document();
    _Wpd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = new Body();
    _Wpd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    _Wpd.Package.Flush(); // _Wpd.Dispose();
}
```

And the save method looks like this:

```
public void SaveToFile(string fullFileName)
{
    _Wpd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

    _Wpd.Package.Flush();

    _Ms.Position = 0;
    var buf = new byte[_Ms.Length];
    _Ms.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

    using (FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(fullFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
    {
        fs.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    }
}
```

And it works fine. Try this.

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me the same error when I try to open it :(

Comment: Sorry for such a late response. I've up-voted your answer because of your effort, but it still doesn't work for me. I guess there are some issues in the cross-platform department. I've noticed this behavior with few other writers (like onedrive.live.com, http://evidenceprime.github.io/html-docx-js/test/sample.html etc.) They all generate docx files that are unsuable on Mac. More strange, docx that I can open on Mac, I can't open in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having this issue - it's a bug in open-xml-sdk, reported here: 
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/249

Looks like there was a problem in the _rels/.rels hidden file with the paths, putting an extra backslash that caused problems on the mac.

My current fix/hack was to use an existing empty doc as a template.